# Dockerizing react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

serve -s build

---> b252a9088991
Removing intermediate container cb5c1e2629c9
Step 16/16 : RUN serve -s build
---> Running in c27b54b31108
serve: Running on port 5000
```

created and dockerized  react application using react-app and getting output like above on "docker-compose up" command 
but nothing is showing on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ or http://localhost:5000/

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
   build: .
   image: react-cli
   container_name: react-cli
   volumes:
   - .:/app
   ports:
   - '3000:3000'
```

above  my docker-compose.yml file

```
FROM scratch
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6.12.0

RUN npm install -g npm --prefix=/usr/local
RUN ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

CMD [ "/bin/sh" ]





ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

RUN npm install -g serve
CMD serve -s build
EXPOSE 3000

COPY package.json package.json
COPY semantic.json semantic.json

COPY npm-shrinkwrap.json npm-shrinkwrap.json
RUN npm install gulp-header --save-dev
RUN npm install --no-optional

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --production

RUN serve -s build
```

and this is my Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are not exposing container port on host. I don't see how your compose file looks, but you probably need to add

```
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
```

To your container definition in compose file.

Comment: I just included my docker file and docker compose file

Comment: @shijin you are exposing port 3000 in your files, while `serve` claims that it is serving at 5000. Please change `3000` to `5000` in your files.

Comment: I just use 3000 at both files but still serving at 5000